# image_transport republish via LaunchDescription and remapping

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

How can I start image_transport republish via Launch file?

I tried the following:

```
import launch
import launch.actions
import launch.substitutions
import launch_ros.actions

def generate_launch_description():

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(package='image_tools', node_executable='cam2image', output='screen', node_name='cam2image'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(package='image_transport', node_executable='republish', arguments=[ 
                'raw',
                '--ros-args',
                '-r in:=image',
                'raw', 
                '-r out:=/camera/image_raw'
            ],
            output='screen', node_name='republish')
    ])
```

But from the log I can see that no images are republished:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2020-12-03-15-29-26-520456-db7019ece524-5304
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [cam2image-1]: process started with pid [5315]
[INFO] [republish-2]: process started with pid [5316]
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #1
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #2
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #3
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #4
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #5
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #6
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #7
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #8
[cam2image-1] [INFO] [cam2image]: Publishing image #9
```

What is wrong with my setup? Any idea?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Anthares

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366908/image_transport-republish-via-launchdescription-and-remapping/) by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have changed the way that I define the params for image_transport:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(package='image_tools', node_executable='cam2image', output='screen', node_name='cam2image'),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(package='image_transport', node_executable='republish', output='screen', node_name='republish', remappings=[
            ('in', 'image'),
            ('out', '/camera/image_raw')
        ], arguments=['raw'])
    ])
```

It actually work. I checked with RQT and I can see source and target topics being created and populated: republish is doing his job, it just doesnt produce any log. I should have checked first, sorry!

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) with karma: 60 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0